# Can we have auto link munging for app-store links?

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

If you copy and paste a link from the Windows Phone marketplace website, they have the form:

```
http://www.windowsphone.com/es-es/store/app/lock-screen/f93c89f3-2136-4640-8f58-ecf86aba05b9
```

Would it be possible to do two things:

First, reformat for the correct format that will redirect tot he store on the phone, when browsing from the phone, or the visitor's preferred language when browsing from the web, i.e.:

```
http://windowsphone.com/s?appId=f93c89f3-2136-4640-8f58-ecf86aba05b9
```

Additionally, would it be possible for a quick request to be pinged off to substitute bare links for a link with the app's name? so:

```
http://www.windowsphone.com/es-es/store/app/lock-screen/f93c89f3-2136-4640-8f58-ecf86aba05b9
```

Would become:

```
[Lock Screen](http://windowsphone.com/s?appId=f93c89f3-2136-4640-8f58-ecf86aba05b9)
```

It may be nice in the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3223/windows-phone) to also treat this as a media card type of thing